# How to put A under B with syntactic sugar?

Tags: macros

Say I would love to have a command that would put text `A` under  text `B`. Yet I do not want to write my command arguments in `\commandname{A,B}` fashion. Instead I would love to write something like to write code like this: `\put A \under B` Are such constructs possible with TeX commands and how to create them?

Comment: The `stackengine` package has a command `\stackunder{A}{B}` which will stack a `B` under the `A`.  Likewise, `\stackon{A}{B}` will stack `B` atop `A`.  The vertical spacing and horizontal alignments are settable.

Comment: There is `B \atop A`, but it is for math mode.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you can, but you shouldn't:

```
\def\put#1\under#2{...something with #1 and #2...}
```

You can call it like

```
\put A\under B
```

or

```
\put A\under {BC}
```

There's no way to avoid braces if the second argument consists of more than one token.

Then you'll soon regret doing this, because you'll find out that `\put` is already a LaTeX command and that you are redefining it. If you're talking about Plain TeX, then there's no problem.

Notice that if you call

```
\put A \under B
```

then `#1` will be `A` with a trailing space, that might be significant or not, depending on various factors.

You can read about *delimited* macro arguments in TeX by Topic (`texdoc texbytopic` on your system or [this link](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/plain/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf)) or in the TeXbook.

Comment: Hm...  Why it worked for me `\def\put #1 \under #2{\underset{#1}{#2}}` using `$ \put d \under = $` - there are spaces?

Comment: @Kabumbus You have a space after `#1`; try `\put A\under B` and you'll get into trouble.